# Baked views have vsprintf error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, printf

All views created by cake bake which call 'format' => __() return the following error:

```
vsprintf(): Too few arguments [CORE/Cake/basics.php, line 565]
```

I looked at basics.php, line 565. It is part of the function __(). The code documentation states that  the purpose of this function is to "Returns a translated string if one is found; Otherwise, the submitted message."

The line in question is:

```
return vsprintf($translated, $args);
```

I looked up vsprintf in the php docs. vsprintf accepts 2 arguments. The first being the format, and the next being an array of values.
'
The function call in the view is:

```
'format' => __('Some Text',true);
```

I debugged $translated and $args.

I get `$translated = 'Some Text'` and `$args = array((int)0=>true)`.

From what I see cakephp is passing the correct number of arguments to vsprintf.

How can I fix this error, or is this a bug?

What I have tried that causes the error to go away:
Change the function call to `'format' => __('Some Text')` - omitting the true. Which causes the function to just return $translated skipping the `vsprintf()` call.

Comment: I just noticed that the call to __() that is not working is part of the pagination code created by cake bake and looks like 'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true). Calls to __() that do work would be more like what I used as an example above __('some text',true) works just fine whereas the call to __() from the pagination code fails.

Comment: Why didnt you mention the cakephp version you are working with? This is a crucial piece of information for every cake related question.

Comment: I am using Cake 2.3.5

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a 1.x method in 2.x?
Where did you read that?
The documenation states, that you do not need true anymore as second argument to return the string:

```
'format' => __('Some Text', true)
```

should be

```
'format' => __('Some Text')
```

PS: It is this way for a long time - since 2.0 (and you are using 2.3).

Comment: The baked code is what is putting the true argument in the function call. Sounds like an issue with Cake. I'm having to go back and correct the baked code.

Comment: Your own custom bake templates? I am pretty sure the current cake core templates are fine. Otherwise please show me the code in the template where it is inserting those true values.

Comment: <?php eco \$this->Paginator->counter(array(
        'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true)
        ));

Comment: That is from /cake/console/templates/default/views/index.ctp

Comment: I checked the version of cakephp that bake is using, I found it is 1.3.7. Based on what I read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967312/right-way-to-install-cakephp-scripts-for-v2-2-1 I need to use a different version of bake.

Comment: Yes, you sure do. Always call your cake core / bake shell relevantly from your app dir (`./Console/cake bake ...`or `../lib/Cake/Console/cake bake ...` for example). Then this cannot happen.